# Angular 1.2.17 -> 1.2.18: ng-transclude within ng-repeat, scope differences

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm in the process of upgrading from angularJs 1.2.17 to 1.2.18 and there is some change that is breaking one of the ways that we are using angular. I have been able to reproduce the problem with a jsFiddle.

Are we doing something wrong? Is there a small adjustment that will make the example work with angular 1.2.18?

JSFiddle 1.2.17 (Working): http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8829/

JSFiddle 1.2.18 (Not working): http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8828/

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-init="group = groups[0]">
            <div simple-checkbox></div>  
        </div>
        <div ng-init="group = groups[1]">
            <div image-checkbox></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.groups = [{
        names: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
    },{
        names: ['Four', 'Five', 'Six']
    }];
}

myApp.directive('simpleCheckbox', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        template: '<div checkbox>{{name}}</div>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('imageCheckbox', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        template: '<div checkbox><img ng-src="http://placekitten.com/g/10/10" /> {{name}}</div>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('checkbox', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-repeat="name in group.names"><input type="checkbox" id="{{name}}"><label for="{{name}}" ng-transclude></label></div></div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: These seem very related https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7842 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the help provided in these issues:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7842

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874

Working jsFiddle with Angular 1.2.18:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8828/

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-init="group = groups[0]">
            <div simple-checkbox></div>  
        </div>
        <div ng-init="group = groups[1]">
            <div image-checkbox></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</body>
```

The magic directive

```
myApp.directive('transcludeWithInsideScope', function () {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
                if(transclude) {
                    transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

All of the JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.groups = [{
        names: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
    },{
        names: ['Four', 'Five', 'Six']
    }];
}

myApp.directive('simpleCheckbox', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        template: '<div checkbox>{{name}}</div>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('imageCheckbox', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        template: '<div checkbox><img ng-src="http://placekitten.com/g/10/10" /> {{name}}</div>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('checkbox', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-repeat="name in group.names"><input type="checkbox" id="{{name}}"><label for="{{name}}" transclude-with-inside-scope></label></div></div>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('transcludeWithInsideScope', function () {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
                if(transclude) {
                    transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```